# javascript correct style avoid nested functions

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code that works, but I don't see nested function usually so I think I can write it in a better way:

```
function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    function errorHandlerFS(e) {
      //code managing error
    }

    function onSuccessFS(fs){
         window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI,function(fileEntry){//here I reference the variable imageURI
           //do something
         }, errorHandlerFS);
     }

     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, onSuccessFS, errorHandlerFS);
}

$('#shootImg').click(function(){
        cameraProp.sourceType = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,cameraProp);
});
```

Here the click on #shootImg activates the onSuccess passing imageURI.
Then if window.requestFileSystem succeeds calls onSuccessFS.
Here my problem arises.
Since I need imageURI in onSuccessFS I wrote onSuccessFS nested inside onSuccess. I think this is something to avoid, but if I had written onSuccessFS outside onSuccess the variable imageURI was outside its scope.
Please concentrate only on the javascript.

Comment: Who told you to avoid nested functions? IMHO the above code is quite clean and well-factored.

Comment: Because I don't see them a lot... maybe I never saw nested functions... maybe

Comment: Maybe you haven't seen them because some languages do not support them. In JavaScript, nested functions are often an excellent way to factor and structure logic. Far from nesting `onSuccessFS` inside `onSuccess` being "something to avoid", it's precisely the right way to close over the `imageURI` parameter.

Comment: In JavaScript functions are objects. Since functions are objects, functions can have methods. So what you are doing there is not a violation of any basic JavaScript syntax rules.

Comment: The main reason you don't usually see nested functions is you haven't read enough javascript code. While it's good to avoid writing code using features you're not familiar with, in this case it seems you have understood the utility of inner functions. It's a common idiom in javascript that enforces private functions that shouldn't be exposed outside an API. I do encourage you to read up on closures though. Those inner functions can do more than you think.

Comment: @TheZenCoder To nitpick a bit, nested functions are distinct from methods on function objects, and in any case this is not a matter of syntax--the code compiles and runs, after all--but rather of best practices in structuring code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think this is something to avoid

No, it's not. JavaScript approves this style, and you will sometimes find quite deeply nested functions in totally well-written code.

In contrast to other languages, JavaScript's only scoping device are functions, and so functions are very often used for encapsulation.

> but if I had written onSuccessFS outside onSuccess the variable imageURI was outside its scope.

Well, that nearly enforces you to use a closure. Trying to avoid it only complicates everything.

Answer (score 0):

Basic PhoneGap examples promote an approach similar to what you have above, so i wouldn't say you are doing anything terribly wrong, especially with the nested functions. An advantage of the nested functions is that you can reuse them.

An alternative to nesting the function definitions would be to pass success and error handlers functions directly as params:

```
  function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, 
        function(fs) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI,
                function(fileEntry) { //here I reference the variable imageURI
                    //do something
                }, 
                function(e) {
                   //code managing error
                });
        },
        function(e) {
            //code managing error
        });
  }
```

If you are not happy with this and your code has a tendency to grow, you should think about rewriting this code to be more modular.

You could abstract your local storage logic into a separate .js module that would contain all the logic related to Temporary or Persistent storage, and it would contain all error handling related to storage. That way you would simplify the code above, because the local storage API would be wrapped in a much simpler interface.